# react stateless component with onClick issue

Tags: reactjs

I have a stateless component and i want to be able to click on the image and redirect it to a new page.
The issue that i am having is that i cannot get onClick to work correctly. 
I was trying to write a function within the onClick = {this.ProjectSelected} but this will not work.
Do i have to pass a function (onClick) from the parent to child component? If so how do i do that?
I am able to log the project id to the console.
Thanks for the help.

```
const projectListTemplates = (props) => {
    const { classes } = props;
    return (
        <div>
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <GridList className={classes.gridList}>
                    <GridListTile key="Subheader" cols={2} style={{ height: 'auto' }}>
                        <Subheader component="div">Projects</Subheader>
                    </GridListTile>
                    {props.data.map(item => (
                        <GridListTile key={item.image}>
                            <img src="./images/Project/1.jpg" alt={item.title} />
                            <GridListTileBar
                                title={item.title}
                                subtitle={<span> {item.name}</span>}
                                onClick={()=>console.log(`this project was clicked ${item.id}`)}
                                >

                                </GridListTileBar>
                            />
                            <ProgressBar now={60} />
                        </GridListTile>
                    ))}
                </GridList>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In stateless component we are not defining any local property like state or methods. We have only props and rendering data based on props. We have only props events to trigger. So we have to pass a event function from parent component in order to handle click event. If you want to keep click event locally, convert component to stateful (Class).

#### Stateless

```
const ProjectListComponent = (props) => {
  const { onClick } = props
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick}>Click me</button>
  )
}

class AppComponent extends Component {
  handleClick() {
    console.log('clicked')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ProjectListComponent onClick={this.handleClick} />
    )
  }
}
```

#### Stateful

```
class ProjectListComponent extends Component {
  handleClick() {
    console.log('clicked')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i changed it to a class component and it works now.

Comment: There is typo mistake in stateless props example. I update answer and let me know this helpful or not.